# Building multiple modules together using maven

Tags: java, maven

We have 3 modules say A,B and C.These 3 modules are cross dependent.To compile A I want B and C.To compile B I want A and C.To compile C we want B and A.So how to build these 3 modules together and we want to get A.jar,B.Jar and C.war.

Comment: When starting from scratch, how can this project be built?

Comment: I think maven will raise cyclic dependency error for such scenario. From design perspective as well, such module design is bad.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<dependencies>` section in `pom.xml` to add a dependency for one another module.

Create a parent pom for all of your modules. When building parent, maven builds all children (except if you use `-pl :mymodule` selector on command line). See `parent` section of pom

You can also add a 4th child module D (without artefact, just a pom module) with A, B, and C dependencies or a subset. When you build D, maven compiles A, B, C with the option `-am` (also-make) which forces maven to build the selected module and dependencies too.

Note that you must avoid cyclic dependencies into your code or maven will fail to build your project. If you have a cyclic dependency, extract the code need by two modules into one another and adding a dependency in both

Comment: We have some doubt. Suppose i created a POM D with 3 child A,B and C. While compiling , maven will compile the all the modules together or first it compiles A, then B, then C ? If it compiles together we can maintain the cross dependencies, right?

Answer (score 0):

What you are explaining is the cyclic dependency. Maven does not support cyclic dependencies and your build will fail if your try to do that.

You can create a multi-module maven project. Move all the common functionality to Module A. Add the dependency of Module A in  Module B and Module C's `pom.xml` `<dependencies>...</dependencies>` section.

Maven will build the modules in the order you specify in the parent project `pom.xml` `<modules>...</modules>` section. In this way you create A.jar, B.jar and C.war by defining the `<packaging>...</packaging>`as `jar` or `war` in their respective module's `pom.xml`

These links will be helpful - [link1](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html)  [link2](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html)

Comment: Not only Maven will not support cyclic dependencies. I don't know any build tool which supports cyclic dependencies..

Comment: Yep! Even  I do not believe there exists one.